# content based image retrieval graphical user interface

Tags: matlab

I am making a project named content based image retrieval using color. I have implemented my algorithm. Now I have to make a GUI.

How can I call my algorithm function in the callback function of a push button?

By pushing the button my query and database images should display on GUI.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

[FileName, folderName] = uigetfile('.','specify an image file'); 
fullimageFilename=fullfile(folderName,FileName); im=imread(fullimageFilename); query(im); 
image(im,'parent',handles.axes2);
```

Comment: Can you please post any relevant code and/or your attempt at the problem so far?

Comment: function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
 [FileName, folderName] = uigetfile('*.*','specify an image file');
 fullimageFilename=fullfile(folderName,FileName);
 im=imread(fullimageFilename);
 query(im);
 image(im,'parent',handles.axes2);       i just want to call the query function in the button callback function

Comment: Can you please specify the problem? Aren't you already calling query() within the Callback-function (cf. given code)?

Comment: my basic question is that i want to ask how i can call a user-defined function within gui callback function.plz tell me syntax with an example.

Comment: I want to ask the syntax for calling a external function in a pushbutton callback function.Please tell me.